# postfix not accepting mails from few domains

Tags: postfix, exim

I have a problem with postfix. Our server not accepting the emails from a domains.

On the receiver server logs I see:

```
 postfix/smtpd[4533]: improper command pipelining after DATA from mail.domain.hu[IP address]:
postfix/smtpd[4533]: lost connection after DATA (0 bytes) from mail.domain.hu[IP address]
```

On the sending server logs (it uses exim4):

```
 R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp defer (110): Connection timed out: SMTP timeout while connected to domain [IP]
```

Does anyone have a suggestion what can cause a problem like this? Can a bad (self-signed) SSL cert on the receiving server cause this?

Comment: Can you telnet to port 110 on the receiving server from the sending server?

Comment: Hi, port 110 is POP3, I think it is not related, the problem is between 2 MTA a postfix and an exim.

Comment: The fail2ban came because it is very weird: sometimes a message goes though and get delivered. From 20 times 1 time it is working. I though it is a fail2ban problem, but I put the IP of the sending server to whitelist, the problem still exists. And because of I see all the mail delivery attempts in the log I think it is not a firewall / networking problem

Comment: The sender is misbehaving, in a way that is usually seen only from spam senders. If that's a legitimate mail server, contact its admin because it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Are you only allowing TLS smtp connections? Port 25 should except standard, unencrypted communications. Not all servers support or use TLS.